# Xamarin Android - Creating HTTPs server

Tags: android, xamarin, https, xamarin.android, httplistener

I have requirement in which my mobile application works as server and can handle API. I can do the same by using HttpListener class in Xamarin. But now i want to add support for secure communication i.e HTTPS.

Is there any way to achieve the same.

Comment: You can try to use `Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLServerSocket` to achieve it, but I do not recommand you to make Android application as a https server, Android application have lots of performance limitations or background services limitations.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for update. Will try with SSLServerSocket. What type performance limitations are you talking about? My Application will works as server when application will be in Foreground.

Comment: If you have clients connect to the server, you need to open threads to handle the connection, Application used RAM will be increased fastly, every application have a RAM limiation by Android OS, if your app has reached the heap capacity and tries to allocate more memory, the system throws an `OutOfMemoryError`.Normally, Android application used by a viewer to display the content from server.
 https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory#CheckHowMuchMemory

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for your feedback.